# Live select/show/reload data from MySQL db when delete

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have three pages :

1)index.php (get results from select.php and put them into div#result )

2)select.php (loops into MySQL's table)

3)delete.php (gets user_id as a parameter and deletes it from MySQL's table).

My goal is : After user clicks on delete! to show updated results (after changes/deletes)

from MySQL's table

my problem is I could not know how to tell jQuery: listen process delete.php?id=123 & then

reload select.php while staying in index.php without redirecting to delete.php

so user actually does not see what happens or does not see that he's being redirected to

another page.

index.php

```
<html>
    <title>a</title>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#result').load('select.php');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

select.php

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","123");
    if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: '); }
    mysql_select_db("test", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("select * from users");   

    while($rs3 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $rs3["user_email"]." ".$rs3["user_name"]." ";
        echo "<a href=delete.php?id=".$rs3[user_id].">Delete</a>";
        echo "<br />";
    }
?>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","123");
    if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: '); }
    mysql_select_db("test", $con);

    $id = mysql_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
    $delete = "delete from users where user_id='{$id}'";
    @mysql_query($delete);
?>
```

thank you.

Comment: You are on the right track.  What you need to do is this: on click of 'delete' button use ajax (jquery makes it easy) to call `delete.php` and delete **the row from the table** where the 'delete' button was clicked.  This way you don't need to reload the table.  Of course, you need to delete the row only after receiving successful response from your 'delete.php'

Comment: @eawedat Check out for my Answer Edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create not links, but AJAX query for delete. Make JQuery call for links. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    function refreshContent(){
        $('#result').load('select.php');    
    }

    $('#result').on('click','a',function(event){
        // prevent going by link `href`
        event.preventDefault();

        // get deleting row id
        var ids = $(this).data('ids');

        // make AJAX call for delete
        $.get("delete.php", { id: ids},function(data){
            // on success - refresh tcontent
            refreshContent();
        });

        return false;
    });

    // making content load on start
    $(document).ready(function(){
        refreshContent();
    });

});
</script>
```

Also u must add `ids` in `<a>`. In this line:

```
echo "<a href='delete.php?id=".$rs3[user_id]."' data-ids='".$rs3[user_id]."'>Delete</a>";
```

Comment: I tried another way but I do not know where to post it..because right here in comments there are no colors and my code is long.

Comment: select.php : http://pastebin.com/HgN81Tm5

index.php : http://pastebin.com/HrSVCAL4

Comment: that's rly bad way. coz anyone without JS support cant navigate through your site.

Comment: but.. you load content with js, so dont mind :) but i highly recommend to use jquery method `on`.